# Cond If And Or in Racket

Tags: if-statement, lisp, scheme, racket

Can someone please explain these functions for me in racket. I`m totally lost. Please help me with some examples. Thanks! I just cannot figure these functions out for the life of me.

Comment: Reasons for closing questions include: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself." "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." If you've been experimenting with these operators, what sort of results did you get that were unexpected?  What did you expect?  Please be specific.

Comment: All that said, it _is_ important that you become familiar with these operators, and I'd suggest you take a look at the Racket documentation, particularly [2.12 Conditionals: if, cond, and, and or](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html), which includes descriptions and examples of these operators.

Answer (score 3):

First, the If:

```
(if (positive? 1) 1 -1)
```

Racket first evaluates if 1 is positive (which is the first expresion (positive? 1)). If it is, returns 1, else, return -1. This is equivalent to c-like languages doing:

```
if ( positive?(1))
  return 1
else
  return -1
```

The Cond is basically a if that has multiple options. The equivalent in C-like languages would be else-if

```
(cond [(first-condition) (what-to-do)]
      [(second-condition) (what-to-do)]
      [(third-condition) (you-get-the-idea)])
```

And and Or are just the logical operators, equivalent to && and || in C-like languages

```
(and true true) => true
(and true false) => false

(or true true) => true
(or true false) => true
(or false false) => false
```

Comment: cond is a little more complicated than that, though that is the common use to dispatch on case.

Answer (score 0):

`If` is the turnary operator. It has three arguments, unless the first argument has a value of `#f` it will return the value of the second argument, otherwise the value of the third argument.

`OR` accepts one or more arguments, evaluates them one at a time left to right, and returns the first value if finds that is not `#f`, and returns `#f` if no argument satisfies that condition.

`AND` accepts one or more arguments evaluate them one at a time left to right, if it finds one that is `#f` it returns `#f`, otherwise it returns the value of the last argument that it evaluates.

`COND` accepts one or more arguments, each with one or more sub arguments (2 is the usual number though). It evaluates each argument left to right one at a time by evaluating the first subargument. If it is not `#f` then it evaluates each of the rest of the sub-arguments (if any) in order and returns the value of the last argument. Otherwise it moves onto the next argument and evaluates it the same way. `else`  is a special sytax within these sub-arguments that is always treated as if it is not `#f`.

And here argument is understood to mean any valid s-expression.

Answer (score 0):

NB: If you are familiar with non-lisp languages this is the answer for you. I'm not trying to explain them in other way than other code. Other answers do however so this is just a supplement.

None of those are functions, but special forms.

```
(if predicate 
    consequent 
    alternative)
```

is pretty much like Algol-dialects `if`

```
if( predicate )
{
   consequent
}
else
{
   alternative
}
```

Note that predicate, consequent and alternative can be anything from a complex expression to a simple value.

`cond` works more like an if, elseif..., else:

```
(cond (predicate1 consequent1)
      (predicaten consequentn)
      (else alternative))
```

`and` works like `&&` in algol dialects. Thus `false && print("Do it!")` doesn't print anything since it short circuits.

```
(and #f (display "Do it!")) ; ==> #f (and does not display anything since first term was false)
(and 1 2 3) ; ==> 3 (3 is the last true value.  In Scheme everything except #f is true.)
```

`or` works like `||` in algol dialects. thus `true || print("Do it!")` doesn't print since first term was true.

```
(or 'mama (display "Do it")) ; ==> mama (first true value, does not print "do it")
```